# CSRF token mismatch error in laravel 5 on multiple async ajax request?

Tags: ajax, laravel, asynchronous, token

I'm using Laravel 5.2 for my web application and I have a page with multiple ajax requests by the same event. In $.ajax, I set async: true, Sometimes it shows CSRF token Mismatch error and redirect to login page. However when I set Async: false in ajax, it works fine but it takes lots of time.

Please help me so that it does not show token mismatch error.

Answer (score 0):

in your form create one hidden filed name _token you can use this helper method to generate field

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

in javascript you have to fetch this field value

```
var token = $( "input[name='_token']" ).val();

$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston",_token:token }
});
```

another way create hidden a span or div add data attribute to it

```
<div id="token" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}"></div>
```

fetch in javascript data value

```
var token = $( "#token" ).data('token');

$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston",_token:token }
});
```

Comment: i have already used                                                                             <meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/> in my app.blade.php and                                                                            $.ajaxSetup({
   headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
}); but, its not working.                                                                                     I was sending in a bunch of ajax requests at once and some were failing. It was random on when they would succeed and fail.

Answer (score 0):

You said you use

> $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') } });

Maybe somewhere headers in request overrides, try to change it on

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') );
    }
});
```

Comment: I have used the above code, but the problem still persist. :( :(

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your url variable like so :

```
url: '/my-route'+'?_token=' + '{{ csrf_token() }}',
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to cater this scenario (handing concurrent async requests) in session based CSRF implementation.

Consider 2 async request, r1 and r2:
both are sync and hit at the same time for same session on the CSRF Filter.

r1 changes the CSRF token value which is stored for session id and completes its implementation.

whereas r2 gets TOKEN_MISMATCH since, it has the same old token in the request header which is now get expired by r1 request completion.

So, for r2, CSRF filter will raise error.